# Como puedo tomar el valor de un campo de una tabla y agregarlo a un input al hacer click en este campo

Tags: html5

Un saludo, quisiera que al hacer click sobre un campo de una tabla como ejemplo `<tr><td>Juan</td><tr>` un campo de texto tomara este mismo valor, me podrian ayudar muchas gracias

Comment: que tal si nos proporcionas algo de código que actualmente estés trabajando.

Comment: Te he dejado un ejemplo, espero te sirva.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por la escasa información que has proporcionado esto es algo similar a lo que buscas, empleando jQuery en lugar de javascript puro.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".name").click(function(){ // Al hacer clic en la función
        var value = $(this).text(); // Obtengo el valor del texto cliqueado
        $('#miinput').val(value); // Seteo el valor en el campo de texto
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td>
    <a href="#" class="name">Juan<a>
  </td>
  <td>
    <a href="#" class="name">Pedro<a>
  </td>
  <td>
    <a href="#" class="name">Susana<a>
  </td>
</tr>  
<br />
<input id="miinput" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo un ejemplo de lo que estas buscando.

```js
var a = document.querySelectorAll("table td"); //Buscamos todos los td que exitan en las tablas
if(a != undefined || a != null){ //Verificamos que si existan
  for(var b in a){ //Iteramos el array: a
    var c = a[b]; //Obtenemos el TD de la iteracion
    if(typeof c == "object"){ //Obtenemos solo los objetos
      c.onclick = function (){ //Asignamos el evento Click
        var tbl = document.querySelector("table"); //Buscamos la tabla
        tbl.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend','<p>'+this.outerText+'</p>'); //Insertarmos despues de la tabla el texto que hemos recuperado del TD
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td>campo a</td><td>campo b</td></tr>
</table>
```

Tal vez sea necesario adecuarlo a tus necesidades particulares.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que he entendido es que quieres que al hacer click sobre un `<td>` su valor se muestre en un textbox (`<input />`).

```js
var nameTxt = document.getElementById('txt-nombre');
var peopleTbl = document.getElementById('tbl-personas');
var cells = peopleTbl.querySelectorAll('tbody td');
cells.forEach(function(cell) {
 
  cell.onclick = function() {
    nameTxt.value = this.innerText;
  };
});
```

```html
<table id="tbl-personas">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Nombre</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Luis Sánchez</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input type="text" id="txt-nombre" />
```